# About convergent sequence in the finite complement topology on $\mathbb R$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I was working on the problem: Show that if $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R$ having infinite range, then $\{x_n\}$ converges to every point in $\mathbb R$ with the finite complement topology on $\mathbb R$.

At first I thought I have found a proof, but after some further consideration, I feel like the question might not be correct. Here is my concern:

Define $x_n=\begin{cases} n, \text{if n is odd}\\ 0, \text{if n is even}\end{cases}$. It's obvious that $\{x_n\}$ has infinite range.

For $y\in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$, let $U=\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$. Clearly, $U$ is an open set that contains $y$. Nevertheless, for any $M\in \mathbb N$, there exists $m\ge M$ such that $x_m=0$, so $x_m\notin U$. Hence $\{x_n\}$ does not converge to y.

If the problem is indeed correct, then did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: Fyi this topology is often called the ‘cofinite’ topology

Comment: This hinges on what is meant by “infinite range” of a sequence

Comment: @FShrike A sequence is a function with domain $\Bbb N$. So usually the range of a sequence means the image (or range) of the function.

Comment: I think your counter example is correct, if infinite range is taken as the range is infinite. I believe the statement is true if the range of the of the sequence misses only finitely many natural numbers.

Comment: @GBA You mean finitely many reals, right?

Comment: @jjagmath In which case, the problem is mistaken. Perhaps the author meant “if the sequence diverges to $\pm\infty$…” in which case I think the statement is correct

Comment: @FShrike Yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the counter example is correct.

The problem should use a stricter condition than 'infinite range'.
The sequence $(x_n)$ should not be allowed to takes the same values infinitely many times.
That is, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the set $\{n\in\mathbb{N} \: |\: x_n = x\}$ is finite.
Then the sequence converges to every point in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I have the same feeling.